# Azure AD - openid connect post_logout_redirect_uri when user does have a session

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a addtional parameter & or workaround to get post_logout_redirect_uri to work if logout does not resolve internally in azure to a session. I am guessing no session & thus unkonwn client & thus no redirect? Just adding client_id=... does not seem to help.

I mean getting an uri to repeatable redirect back to app.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Flogout%2F%3F&client_id=<...>

Want to do this for a specific tennant rather than common but I guess its the same.

Comment: So the user does not have a session in Azure AD? And it does not redirect the user back to your app in that case?

Comment: Yes, asking if user does not have a session - is it possible to still get a redirect e.g. able to write a uri & repeatable use it and get redirected.
Don't want the logout to end up with close the window.

Comment: So do you have any suggestion or is it impossible?
Can you create an uri that one always can open & redirects back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft response: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/60633/azure-ad-openid-connect-post-logout-redirect-uri-w.html#answer-64473

"Based on the internal discussions, I would say that, without session the logout redirect fails, since otherwise, it's an attack vector for open redirects."

They haven't specified how/why deeper thou.

Answer (score 1):

**You need an active session** to be redirected to *post_logout_redirect_uri*, which usually is the case when calling the *end_session_endpoint*.